# VHD Boot failure in Hyper-V (Win7 boot from vhd)

Tags: windows-7, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, vhd

I've have a virtual machine with a VHD image that I've copied from Windows 7 to the Hyper-V server. This image was created on Windows 7 (Windows 7 64-bit), and I'm using it on Windows 7 as boot image. Starting this virtual machine with the Hyper-V Manager gives this error: "Boot failure. Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device."

What do I need to do to boot from this vhd in Hyper-V?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like the HAL is screwed, boot the image in Win7 again and remove the Virtual PC extensions. Then run sysprep on it and make sure you select the generalise option. Once shutdown copy it over to Hyper-V and try boot it again.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to note is, did you add the VHD as a SCSI drive in Hyper-V? Hyper-V doesn't support booting from a virtual SCSI drive.